# Remove exact text in Cell A if it exists in Cell B

Tags: excel, duplicates, merging-data

I have two Excel columns:

**First column**

```
1. Dog
2. Gorilla
3. Lion
```

**Second column**

```
1. Dog; Monkey; Fish
2. Insect; Cobra
3. Lion; Cat
```

What I want is removing the duplicate from column 2, so if it is in Column A it must be removed:

```
1. Monkey; Fish
2. Insect; Cobra
3. Cat
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Will there only ever be either zero entries or one entry from column A present in a given column B entry? Or could you have a column B entry such as Dog; Monkey; Fish; Gorilla?

Comment: Have you tried anything like formula or macro?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B1,$A1,""),";",""))," ","; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

EEM, that did the trick! Only all semicolons are now gone, but that can be fixed i think. Thanks!